# Using ('s) for "is"

Tags: punctuation, possessives, contractions, orthography

Can I write name then using ('s). For example Janny's 18 years old?

Comment: The possessive tag was added later by a *different* user, the OP never said *anything* about **'s** being possessive in  "Janny's 18 years old" The original tag was "grammar".

Answer (score 10):

Yes, you can, but I would only write it if you want to transcribe an oral conversation. Which means, in spoken language it's common, but not in writing.

By adding the `possessive` tag Brian points to a problem: *Janny's* could also be use as possessive: "Janny's children", so that could be a bit confusing.

Comment: The pronouns `it`, `he`, and `she` have special possessive forms, `its`, `his`, and `her`. So unlike with proper nouns, you can use `'s` in conjunction with these pronouns without being ambiguous with the possessive form.

Comment: it highly depends on the *type* of writing. if it's conversational writing, it's rather common to use a contraction like this: *"Jenny's going to be in late today"* is perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. And you can also use *'s* for *has*, as in

> ***Janny's gotten*** Sally's 18-year-old a new bicycle helmet. Sally's very thankful for the gift.

The three *'s* mean, respectively, *has*, possessive, and *is*.

Comment: And *does*, as in "What's that mean?"

Comment: *Janny's* would never mean *Janny does*, so the point of my response is to point out various meanings of *Janny's* or *Sally's*.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that would be the short (colloquial) form for

"Janny **is** 18 years old".

Note: it can't be possessive. if it meant 'the child of Janny' it shoud be an adjective and couldn't be plural:

"Janny's 18-**year** old [child]"

Comment: But, as @stevenvh said, it is a very unusual thing to write unless transcribing spoken English.  It would look like something a young child might write.